# The validation in interactive grid in oracle apex

Tags: grid, report, oracle-apex, interactive

My problem is that the validation is not working well in interactive grid in my application. I have tried all the possible ways, but nothing is working. The validation works well in the interactive report, but not with the interactive grid.
The problem is that the error message keeps appear even if the data is correct. EX: if the validation condition is "Column is not null", the error message is shown even if I fill the column with data.
..
Another thing, if I made the option of value required on, the same problem appears.
Is their anything to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious about how the validation worked for Interactive Report, anyway here's an example about how to create page validations:

In your Interactive Grid Page, navigate to validations and make sure that editable region and column are set up correctly.

[image]

When you run the page, you'll be able to see the error message when column is null. Once the column has a value, it will possible to save the changes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing what the solution states, however, the error notification message "1 Error has ocurred" followed by the validation error message doesn't show up, I just get a red frame with an X icon on the field, and when saving, it just shows a notification message "Correct errors before saving". For the validations, The editable region and column are set up correctly, just like on the example image.